# How do you open a .vce file in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

I have a `.vce` file to open. Does someone know which app(s) is needed to view this file in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Did you look here: http://techawakening.org/convert-vce-files-to-pdf/167/? I get the impression this file format requires software that runs on MS Windows.

Comment: @vasa1 It does need to run on Windows using [Visual CertExam Suite](http://www.avanset.com/purchase/visual-certexam-suite.html) which some report can be run in Wine.http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=201873

Answer (score 3):

VCE extensions can be open with the Visual CertExam Manager. It is a great application to use when preparing for any type of exams.

1. First you have to install [wine](http://www.winehq.org/) .
2. Then install [Visual CertExam Manager](http://www.visualcertexam.com/dwnl/visual-certexam-manager.html)

   -download it first (using above link)

   -go to the downloaded folder and right click to the

   > visual_certexam_suite_setup.exe

   and select

   > open with wine windows program loader

   -do the steps they ask.(simply now `VCE` installed)
3. Now go to the place that `.vce` file is in and open it through wine(right click /open with wine).

Comment: Link for Visual CertExam Manager isn't working, and I could not find a valid one :(

Comment: just google it .You can find many places who gives Visual CertExam Manager free :)

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to pay for full functionality, but there is an otherwise simple web-based solution: https://vcetrainer.com/

Just upload the file as it says there. You can take the exam in your browser and/or download it as a PDF. But if you don't pay, only the first four questions are visible unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Hello if you want to open the VCE File in Ubuntu then there are a web based VCE exam simulator which will help you to edit and create the VCE file. You can also convert the [VCE to PDF](http://technosoups.com/open-vce-file-convert-vce-pdf-vce-pdf-converter-free-download/) for the better experience. The web-based VCE exam simulator us http://vcetrainer.com. So, try it I hope the above information will be more helpful for you.

Thank You
Technosoups